# How to Add Number of Employees from Last Year to Next Year Dynamically in PowerBi DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a Employee Data in excel which contains Employee data like, Employee Name, FatherName, Designation, Department and two dates Columns, **"LastPromotionDate"** and **"EligibilityDates"**.
Now I made Measure in Dax which is calculating the Total Number of Employees who are not promoted yet using **"EligibilityDates"** Column. Because those who have eligibility dates in the past years,Means they were eligible and yet to be promoted thats why there eligibility dates are in the past. So I made a measure which is calculating the **"totalEmployesNotPromotedtill2023"** and I got the Answer. Lets say its **"100"**.
Now What i want to do is to Add this Number in the Current Year 2024 and the upcoming years, Eligible Candidates.
For Example: I have already **"totalEmployesNotPromotedtill2023"** which is **100**,Now i have **20** Emplopyees in **2024** who are going to be promoted. So the Column Chart will show **120** Employees in **2024** who are yet to be promoted. Next there are **30** Employees who are going to be promoted in **2025**, Then We have **120** Employees in **2024**, It will add in **2025** and becomes **150** in **2025** and soo on.
So what we are trying to achieve is that we are trying to find that how many employees are going to be promoted in the coming years and its increasing year by year.If not promoted.
Can anyone help me related to this problem?
Thanks

I tried to add **"totalEmployesNotPromotedtill2023"** to the Eligible candidates but its adding 100 in each and every year again and agai. thats not what i want.I want to add this Measure in Current Year only and then the Current Year value will add to the Next Year and so on.
I also tried Chatgpt, But cant figured out yet.

```
TotalNotPromotedAccumulated = 
VAR MaxYear = YEAR(TODAY())
VAR BaseCount = [TotalNotPromotedTill2023]

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    BaseCount,
    FILTER(
        ALL('YourTable'[EligibilityDates]),
        YEAR('YourTable'[EligibilityDates]) <= MaxYear
    )
) +
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('YourTable'),
    ALL('YourTable'),
    YEAR('YourTable'[EligibilityDates]) = MaxYear + 1
)
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant Dax expressions used, together with any relevant data tables.

Comment: Ok let me edit the Question

Answer (score 1):

I solved my Issue using this DAX:

```
CumulativeEligibleEmployees = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Employees'),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Calendar'),
        'Calendar'[Year] <= MAX('Calendar'[Year])
    )
)
```

Actually What i did is just Added the previous Year Value to the Next Year and Made some Cumulative Measure. And Applied Filter.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to get the cummulative count for eligibility dates, by year. Let's assume you data starts on 2023, you can try something like this:

```
CALCULATE (
    COUNT(Table[EligibilityDates]),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Table[EligibilityDates] ),
        Table[EligibilityDates] <= MAX ((Table[EligibilityDates]))
    )

)
```

Comment: Dats not working,Do you have idea about cumulative counting? Like if we just sum the last year to the next year,how can we do that?

Comment: It should work, since your filter is on Table[EligibilityDates]. As you can see, the values from the count  will be filtered based on MAX(Table[EligibilityDates]). So, for example, if you filter 2020, it should limit all values till 2020 (cummulative). I would have to test it to see what is the error.